# Access an element's Binding

Tags: aurelia

I have a custom attribute that processes authentication data and does some fun stuff based on the instructions.

```
<div auth="disabled: abc; show: xyz; highlight: 123">
```

There's a lot of complicated, delicate stuff happening in here and it makes sense to keep it separate from semantic bindings like `disabled.bind`. However, some elements will have application-logic level bindings as well.

```
<div auth="disabled.bind: canEdit" disabled.bind="!editing">
```

Under the covers, my auth attribute looks at the logged in user, determines if the user has the correct permissions, and takes the correct action based on the result.

```
disabledChanged(value) {
    const isDisabled = this.checkPermissions(value);
    if (isDisabled) {
        this.element.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

This result needs to override other bindings, which may or may not exist. Ideally, I'd like to look for an existing Binding and override it ala binding behaviors.

```
constructor(element) {
    const bindings = this.getBindings(element); // What is the getBindings() function?
    const method = bindings['disabled']
    if (method) {
        bindings['disabled'] = () => this.checkPermission(this.value) && method();
    }
}
```

The question is what is this `getBindings(element)` function? How can I access arbitrary bindings on an element?

**Edit**: Gist here: https://gist.run/?id=4f2879410506c7da3b9354af3bcf2fa1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>The `disabled` attribute is just an element attribute, so you can simply use the built in APIs to do this. Check out a runnable example here: https://gist.run/?id=b7fef34ea5871dcf1a23bae4afaa9dde</s>

Using `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute` (since the `disabled` attribute does not really have a value, its mere existence causes the element to be disabled), is all that needs to happen:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';


@inject(Element)
export class AuthCustomAttribute {
  constructor(element) {
    this.el = element;
  }

  attached() {
    let val = false;
    setInterval(() => {
      if(this.val) {
        this.el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        this.el.removeAttribute('disabled');
      }
      this.val = !this.val;
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

NEW RESPONSE BELOW

You need to work directly with the binding engine. A runnable gist is located here: https://gist.run/?id=b7fef34ea5871dcf1a23bae4afaa9dde

Basically, you need to get the original binding expression, cache it, and then replace it (if `auth === false`) with a binding expression of `true`. Then you need to unbind and rebind the binding expression:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Parser} from 'aurelia-binding';


@inject(Element, Parser)
export class AuthCustomAttribute {
  constructor(element, parser) {
    this.el = element;
    this.parser = parser;
  }

  created(owningView) {
    this.disabledBinding = owningView.bindings.find( b => b.target === this.el && b.targetProperty === 'disabled');

    if( this.disabledBinding ) {
      this.disabledBinding.originalSourceExpression =  this.disabledBinding.sourceExpression;

      // this expression will always evaluate to true
      this.expression = this.parser.parse('true');
    }
  }

  bind() {
    // for some reason if I don't do this, then valueChanged is getting called before created
    this.valueChanged();
  }

  unbind() {
    if(this.disabledBinding) {
      this.disabledBinding.sourceExpression =  this.disabledBinding.originalSourceExpression;
      this.disabledBinding.originalSourceExpression = null;

      this.rebind();

      this.disabledBinding = null;
    }
  }

  valueChanged() {
    if(this.disabledBinding ) {
      if( this.value === true ) {
        this.disabledBinding.sourceExpression =  this.disabledBinding.originalSourceExpression;
      } else {
        this.disabledBinding.sourceExpression = this.expression;
      }

      this.rebind();

    } else {
      if( this.value === true ) {
        this.el.removeAttribute('disabled');
      } else {
        this.el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      } 
    }
  }

  rebind() {
    const source = this.disabledBinding.source;
    this.disabledBinding.unbind();
    this.disabledBinding.bind(source);
  }
}
```

It is important that the attribute clean up after itself, as I do in the `unbind` callback. I'll be honest that I'm not sure that the call to `rebind` is actually necessary in the unbind, but it's there for completeness.

Comment: The important takeaway from this answer is to remember that Aurelia doesn't force you to work with some arcane custom API when all you want to do is set an attribute value on an element. And, note in my runnable gist how Aurelia keeps track of the value of the disabled attribute changing.

Comment: Appreciate the effort but it doesn't answer the question. I need the auth attribute to override the binding behavior of disabled, which may or may not exist. I've extended your gist and added it to the original question to demonstrate. I'd love to get Jeremy to weigh in, he'll know the answer.

Comment: Ohhhhhh.. okay. that would be more difficult, but it's possible.. let me work on that.

Comment: I've updated the answer and the gist. It does what you want now. You owe me lunch next time you're in town :-)

Comment: + a beer. Looking like 2018, so stay tuned.

Comment: Hi, have you tried this with custom components? I have a hard time getting this to work in a good way. Maybe you can have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022178/how-to-disable-a-custom-component-with-authorize-custom-attribute-in-aurelia

Comment: @AshleyGrant did you get your lunch and/or beer?

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis still owes me that beer 