# How to disable a custom component with authorize custom attribute in Aurelia

Tags: typescript, custom-component, aurelia

I'm trying to create some authorization logic for my custom components. What I want to achieve is that I can set an attribute which disables the component entirely, e.g. when a user has read-only rights. I tried with a button but am not really satisfied with it. I'm basing my work upon the solution to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783364/access-an-elements-binding/44810145)

**my-button.html:** (currently html only)

```
<template bindable="icon, disabled">
  <require from="./buttons.css"></require>

  <button class="btn btn-danger" disabled.bind="disabled">
      <slot>Enter text</slot>
      <i if.bind="icon" class="fa fa-${icon}"></i>
  </button>
</template>
```

**parent.html:**

```
<my-button authorized.bind="false" click.delegate="doSmth()" icon="home">NotAuth</my-button>
```

This does not really work unfortunately, maybe I'm doing something wrong here.
My workaround was to add a `disabled` class to the element where the attribute is attached to, in the attribute's valueChanged method:

```
private valueChanged() {
    if (this.disabledBinding) {
    [...]    
    } else {
      if (this.value === true) {
        this.el.removeAttribute('disabled');
        this.el.classList.remove('disabled');
      } else {
        this.el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        // Added this class so that all child elements cannot be clicked, also for custom components.
        this.el.classList.add('disabled');
      }
    }
  }
```

together with

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This works quite ok, but the styling still needs to be performed then, possibly on each element since they can differ. This then brings me to add a disabled.bind expression to specific elements, to apply their individual disabled styles. This removes the benefit of the great auth attribute I think.

Is there any way this works with custom components?

Comment: Can you show your VM `my-button.ts`?

Comment: Currently there is none. It's a html only component, if that can be called a component actually...

Comment: The parent assigns the property `authorized` and the component binds to the property `disabled`.

Comment: Yes i know, the disabled should actually be not needed at all. Maybe I should've removed it as well for this example. But I need it eventually to make it work in my current code.

Comment: And the disabled property is also there if the component should be used in a scenario independent of authorization - application state for example.